# Jquery File Upload not working inside a div element

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I am using Jquery File Upload plugin with my ASP.NET MVC project. The issue is that "Add files" button doesn't work inside a div,doesn't give any reaction like opening file explorer when I click on,  only works directly inside body. Also, I don't get any errors in console.

My View:

```
    @using MUKAL_Education.Models
@model AddLectureModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-unobtrusive")
@section scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/LectureEdit.css")" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-iframe.transport.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        function findTagByText(text) {
            var jSpot = $("a:contains(" + text + ")")
                .filter(function () { return this.text === text; });
            return jSpot;
        }

        var removeDuplicatesInPlace = function (arr) {
            var ret, len, i, j, cur, found;
            ret = [];
            len = arr.length;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                cur = arr[i];
                found = false;
                for (j = 0; !found && (j < len); j++) {
                    if (cur === arr[j]) {
                        if (i === j) {
                            ret.push(cur);
                        }
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/Lecture/UploadFiles',
                autoUpload: true,
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
                    $('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
                    $('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
                }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            });


            $("#tag_button").click(function() {
                var tags = $("#tag-input").val().trim().replace("<","").replace(">","").split(",");
                tags = removeDuplicatesInPlace(tags);
                var existing_tags = [];
                $("#tag-container .tag").each(function() {
                    existing_tags.push($(this).text());
                });
                var tag_list = tags;
                for (raw_tag in tags) {
                    if ($.inArray(tags[raw_tag], existing_tags) != -1) {
                        findTagByText(tags[raw_tag]).fadeTo('slow', 0.5).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
                        delete tag_list[raw_tag];
        }
        }
                for (myTag in tag_list) {
                    if(tag_list[myTag] != "") { 
            var tag = "<a class='tag'>" + tag_list[myTag] + "<i class='fa fa-times'><i/></a>";
            $("#tag-container").append(tag);
                    }
                }
                $(".tag i").click(function () {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });
        $("#tag-input").val("");
            });
            $(".tag i").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
    });
    </script>
}
<div class="row">
    <div id="add-form" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Lecture", new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "errors"})){
            <div class="row">
                <div id="box-container" class="col-md-7">
                    <div id="add_title">
                        <div id="box-header" class="col-md-12"><h3>Ders Başlığı</h3><hr /></div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, string.Empty, new {@class = "col-md-8 col-md-offset-1"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="box-container" class="col-md-5">
                    <div id="category">
                        <div id="box-header" class="col-md-12"><h3>Kategori</h3><hr /></div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategory, Model.DropdownList.ToSelectList(x => x.CategoryName, x => x.CategoryName, "Kategori Seçiniz"), string.Empty, new {id = "category-dropdown", @class = "bootstrap-select col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"})
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="box-container" class="col-md-7">
                    <div id="description">
                        <div id="box-header" class="col-md-12"><h3>Açıklama</h3><hr /></div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, string.Empty, new {@class = "col-md-8 col-md-offset-1"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="box-container" class="col-md-5">
                    <div id="add_tag">
                        <div id="box-header" class="col-md-12"><h3>Etiketler</h3><hr /></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tags, string.Empty, new {@class = "col-md-8 col-md-offset-1", id = "tag-input"})
                            <button id="tag_button" class="col-md-2">Ekle</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="tag-container">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        }
        <div class="row">
            <div id="box-container" class="col-md-7">
                <div id="file_upload">
                    <div id="box-header" class="col-md-12"><h3>Döküman Ekle</h3><hr /></div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                            <span>Add files...</span>
                            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                        </span>
                        <br />
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
                                <span class="sr-only">0% complete</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="file_name"></div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="file_type"></div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="file_size"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

LectureEdit.css :

```
    .main-content {
    background: #ebebeb;
}

#add-form {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
#add-form #box-container {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
#add-form input  {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    margin-top: .75em;
    height: 2em;
    color: #777;
}
#add-form input:focus,#add-form input:active {
    outline: none;
}

.bootstrap-select {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}

.bootstrap-select option:hover {
    background: #fff !important;
}


.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
    background: transparent;
}

#add_title,#category,#description,#add_tag,#file_upload {
    min-height: 12em;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#add_title,#category {
    margin-top: 3em;
}

#description,#add_tag,#file_upload {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
#box-header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#box-header h3 {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
#box-header hr {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
#category-dropdown {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    margin-top: .75em;
    height: 2em;
}
#tag_button {
    margin-top: .75em;
    height: 2em;
    background: #27AE60;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
a.tag {
    float: left;
    margin-left: .5em;
    margin-top: .5em;
    padding: .5em;
    background: #2980b9;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tag i {
    margin-left: .5em;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.tag:hover > .fa-times {
    visibility: visible;
}
.fa-times {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#tag-container {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

I don't need to add controller and model, they don't have to do with this issue but I can reference [this](http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-upload-a-file-using-mvc-3-and-ajax) as the way I follow.

I will be greatful to people helping for solving this issue and discovering the reasons.

**EDIT:** Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8xswoy8x/1/ , the view is not the same with original I suppose this is because of external resources loaded from GitHub but it can reproduce the issue.

Comment: What you mean "not working"? What happens when you click it? You get any JS errors? Are you sure it is not because of some bad design, e.g. hiding the button?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Button is not hidden but it doesn't give any reaction and I dont get any error in console.Normally it should open file explorer when I click on.

Comment: Just a hunch, but what if you put the fileupload element directly inside the "container" div, and not inside the span? I suspect the bootstrap button can't really contain file input.

Comment: @ShadowWizard When I do that, a classic file input working correctly shows up under "Add files" span. but a classic file input isn't what I want.

Comment: So sounds like your issue is with the design, i.e. bootstrap, and not with jQuery as the title implies

Comment: Yes you might be right, but the title already remarks that the plugin (Jquery File Upload) doesn't work inside a div and it is what my problem is. If it is a design issue, why does the button react so when it is in a div and how can I solve it?

Comment: Not sure yet, will have to try and reproduce. If you can do it yourself on jsfiddle, it would be great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87174/discussion-between-kerem-zaman-and-shadow-wizard).